# External Device reports no Protocol

Tags: iphone, external-accessory

I have an app that I have been working on and I am now at the point that I want to integrate some interaction with an external device via the dock connector. The device that I am using (the iDive 300) conforms to the Made For iPod program. I have written a separate simple app based on the EADemo code to gather information about the device. However, when I run this app the iDive reports nothing for the Name, Serial Number, Firmware, etc and also says that no protocols were found. I know this simple app is working correctly because I have connected to several other external devices and the Name, serial number, etc is populated for each device.

The other odd thing is that the iDive seems to work properly when plugged into my iPhone 4 (i.e. it will increase the volume and play songs and videos found on my iPhone via the buttons on the device). Shouldn't this mean that some protocol is in place for this device to communicate with the iPhone? Is it all possible for me to read data from this device (e.g. capture when the 'play','menu', or other buttons are pressed) if I don't know the protocol?

I am completely new to the External Accessories framework and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should autopsy the app that is associated with iDive. In its info.plist, there should be a key:

```
UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols
```

whose value is an array([See this for the formal definition](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW4)), and within it lies a string whose value looks like a reversed domain name, as the device protocol.

You should edit your Info.plist, add the key(`'Supported external accessory protocols'` in plain English) for an array, put in the protocol as its item.

Comment: Hello I have a question as I am developing app for the Mfi registered device that where can I get the protocol for entering it into plist? I have Mfi profile credentials with me.

Comment: If you haven't got one, just choose a string that is not used, like what you did choosing an App Id. If you are developing app for an existing device, then ask the manufacturer about its protocol string. Remember whatever you do, the string in the app and the one in the device must always match.

Comment: Alright Thanks for that. I was wondering that if that protocol might be available inside the given mfi portal. But I did not get any. So this might be available with manufacturer of device. Also as I am a beginner for this can you help me providing useful tutorial link for external accessory demo. I have gone through developers site(EAdemo), other stackoverflow questions. But a clean tutorial is hard to find. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is good advice, but note that adding the protocol to the info plist isn't necessary to detect the connection and get the model, manufacturer, etc information.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that an accessory actually uses EA. It may communicate using the protocols defined by Apple.

EA is only necessary if you want to communicate using your own proprietary protocol.

Check the EADemo example from Apple... If it doesn't show up in the demo app, it's not EA.